# what that mean 'the type serializer factory could not load its parameters from the configuration'?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-batch

I have a problem when I run this command

```
 ./bin/flink run -p 4 -q examples/gelly/flink-gelly-examples_*.jar --algorithm PageRank --input CSV --type integer --simplify directed --input_filename WikiTalk.txt --input_field_delimiter $'\t'     --output print
```

I'm using VM and my cluster consists of 3 taskmanagers and the master is jobmanager and taskmanager too (4 taskmangers and one job manager)

part of the exception

```
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobResult.toJobExecutionResult(JobResult.java:146)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.rest.RestClusterClient.submitJob(RestClusterClient.java:265)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The initialization of the DataSource's outputs caused an error: The type serializer factory could not load its parameters from the configuration due to missing classes.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.DataSourceTask.invoke(DataSourceTask.java:106)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:704)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The type serializer factory could not load its parameters from the configuration due to missing classes.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.util.TaskConfig.getTypeSerializerFactory(TaskConfig.java:1143)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.util.TaskConfig.getOutputSerializer(TaskConfig.java:549)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.BatchTask.getOutputCollector(BatchTask.java:1230)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.BatchTask.initOutputs(BatchTask.java:1309)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.DataSourceTask.initOutputs(DataSourceTask.java:312)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.DataSourceTask.invoke(DataSourceTask.java:103)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flink.graph.Edge
```

Comment: Which Flink version are you using?

Comment: Could you please retry by specifying the gelly jar directly instead of using a blob? `examples/gelly/flink-gelly-examples_2.11_1.10.jar`

Comment: I'm using flink-1.7.2 version and yes I tried that and I found the same error